# Visualforce Email Template Subject Date Extraction From DateTime field

Tags: visualforce, email-template, date, datetime

I need some help and i am a little confused.

I have the following field `Delivery_Date__c` which is the datatype of `Date/Time`. I know i can extract the date and time separately within my email body, but what i would like to do is extract the date from this field for the subject but really struggling to find a way to do this.

This is my current opening

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact"
    relatedToType="sales_and_marketing__c"
    subject="Schroders – Shipping to: 
        {!relatedTo.Delivery_City__c} – {!relatedTo.Delivery_Date__c}"
    replyTo="abc@test.com" >
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
```

Comment: `{!DATEVALUE(relatedTo.Delivery_Date__c)}`- does this helps?

Comment: You Sit a legend :) I used datetime lol

Comment: Adding it as an answer, to help others facing similar issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visualforce has some OOTB [Date and Time Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm), you can use any one of them as per your requirement.

For date, use:

> **DATEVALUE**- Returns a date value for a date/time or text expression.

For date time, use:

> **DATETIMEVALUE**- Returns a year, month, day and GMT time value.